# Dynamic sized view constraint

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to make the layout work as I want.

So the blue container is a view that will contain a bunch of rendered `UIImageView`s that will be added in `viewDidLoad`. The amount of subviews can vary, so sometimes there might be one row, sometimes two and maybe three.

I want the blue view container to wrap all subviews added, and the Table View should be right under the blue view container, and not overlap the toolbar at the bottom.

Here is a preview of my view.

[image: Preview]

Comment: Start from here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: If you got only a few items then a stackView will be ok. If you have multiple items (like a grid of thumbnails for example) then a collectionView would be the way to go. This can be tricky though since both (collectionview & tableview) are scrollview based views, hence there is no intrinsic content size (their height is not fixed in this case). The key thing to remember when working with autolayout is that you have to provide enough constraints so _position_ and _size_ of every view can be resolved without ambiguity. I hope that this makes sense...